# wrapper around API using reference counting logic C++

Tags: c++

I am going to use heavily some C-API in my C++ application, I have a lot of functions available that I need to call in couple. For example createFoo(void*) at the beginning and freeFoo(void*) when the job is done.

So, I thought to use the RAII idiom, so I created the first wrapper with copy constructor and assignment operator private and not implemented. It works fine, however I would like a richer copy semantic. I would like to use a reference counting copy semantic. I have considered to write my own version but I don't want reinvent the wheel. Also the boost::shared_ptr is already implementing pretty much the behave that I want to achieve.

The only difference is the pointer is not create with new and it is not release with delete. I would like to customize the source and the sink functions.

I have the feeling that is a good way to face the problem, however I cannot come up with a class that implement my idea.

Here are the questions, do you think it is a good way to solve my problem? Is there any open source code that implement something similar? Do you have any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really easy. As an example, suppose you have the C fopen interface:

```
FILE* fopen(blah);
int fclose(FILE*);
```

Then you can wrap FILE resource with shared_ptr like this:

```
shared_ptr<FILE> ptr(fopen("file.txt", "rt"), fclose);
// use the file pointed by ptr
fwrite(..., ptr.get());

// FILE is automatically closed by a call to fclose when 
// reference count drops to zero...
```

**Edit:** Let me explain a bit.`shared_ptr` stores a 'deleter' along with the reference counters for ownership and weak ownership. A deleter is any object that can be called with the pointer to the resource to be freed as an argument. The default deleter simply calls `delete` on its argument, however you can pass your own deleter.

When I apply the technique above, I usually wrap the creation into a separate function. This simplifies the code and allows me to check for error-codes returned from C-style APIs and convert them to exception:

```
shared_ptr<FILE> MakeFile(const char* name, const char* mod)
{
    if(FILE *ptr = fopen(name, mod))
        return shared_ptr<FILE>(ptr, fclose);

    throw SomeExceptionType("fopen", errno, ...);
}
```